# will page menu called by php function affect google indexing?

Tags: php, html, indexing

I have several HTML pages on my website that display the same menu at top. If I need to make a correction, I need to edit and upload all those HTML pages. I have created a php file that will echo out the menu. I am calling this php file at `<body>` through Ajax when the page loads. This is working fine. The question is, since menu is not existing in the HTML files when the google or other indexing bots crawl my pages, will it affect the page ranking in any way?

Comment: I don't know about indexing, but I believe you should etiher have an index file with menu, sidebars, etc and load content to it through AJAX or change the HTML pages to PHP and include the header in each of them. If you stay with your current solution, you don't need to echo the menu in PHP file. You can load HTML files through AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

To make this seamless on the front end you should be doing this on the server not with javascript on the front end

The better way to do this is using php and include(), and if most of your pages are the same you can do this with footer and menu as well, which means that you only have to have what is on the page in each file

What I do in this situations is create the page i want the way it looks and then cut it into three parts ( four if the menu is not directly after the  tag

This makes it very easy to maintain later, other wise you will have different code on every page

example header file ( in this example you would call it header.php )

```
<?php
// header
?>


<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

    <!-- any other style sheets you want to link too go here -->

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<?php

// if your header is the top of the page put it here



// end of file
```

example page this is the page you call ( like index.php will be your first and then name them as you want them

```
<?php
// basic page template

//Header goes here
include('header.php');
// if your header is horizontal and semantically at the top of the page you include your menu in the header.php file

// if your menu is not sematically at the top you can add it in where ever you wish, bottom right left etc
include('menu.php');

?>

<!--           Some page content                -->
<!--           Some page content                -->
<!--           Some page content                -->
<!--           Some page content                -->

<?php

//include your footer
include('footer.php');

// end of file
```

Example footer file ( in this example you would call it footer.php )

```
<?php
// footer file
?>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

<!-- put your javascript in the footer  -->
</body>
</html>

 <?php

// end of file
```

Comment: Thanks jDoGG, but this will make me rename the extensions of all pages from .htm to .php, which I do not want.

Comment: @sridhar why are you concerned about changing page names? if its because of search engines, you can easily fix that with .htaccess, with either mod-rewrite or 301 redirect